# How to horizontally line up divs within a container div so that when you make the window smaller, they "wrap"?

Tags: html, css, center

I am very new to coding so sorry if I don't really know how to ask this question. My teacher wants us to line up a bunch of divs inside of a container div, which I have successfully done. The problem is that he wants it so that when the browser window gets smaller, instead of a scroll bar appearing at the bottom, he wants the divs to start popping below all the other ones. I can get them all to line up and center easily, but I've been trying for 5 hours to get it where they do what he wants and I can't figure it out. Of course, it's 4th of July and the Weekend, so this is my only option. I can't even begin to add all the code I've tried to make this work, but it's all been super basic (it should be, it's a freaking beginner class and I'm 3 weeks in). I can't find anything at all about how to do this, pretty much every video and thing I've read says
`display:flex;`
`align-items: center;`
`justify-content: center`
which works great, it just doesn't "wrap" (is that the word? that's what he was saying, but using that in my searches is not helping one bit).

Anyway, hoping the picture helps explain what on earth I mean. I'm good as far as creating the look and the top image he wants, all I need help with is how to avoid a scroll bar appearing when the window get smaller. Thank you!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3hNT.png)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your container.

CSS Tricks has made a comprehensive guide on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-flex-wrap

Comment: Thank you so much!! I keep getting hung up on the simplest things for hours. Thank you thank you. (But also, nobody has mentioned this at all anywhere so far, so I'm not sure how I would've known this).

Comment: For sure!! For me, MDN, W3Schools, and CssTricks are the best sources for learning this kind of stuff. You can also do the web development course on freecodecamp.